# Can momentum be considered as a measure of inertia of motion?

Tags: kinematics, momentum, inertia

If inertia of motion is a body's tendency to be in motion then can momentum be considered as a measure to calculate that tendency to be in motion?

Comment: Any reason why specifically momentum, but not kinetic energy? Or both?

Comment: Yes what I believe the inertia, is about conservation of momentum.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming idealistic collisions, a 1kg ball moving at 100 m/s and a 100 kg ball moving at 1 m/s. Now both have the same momentum: 100 kg$\times$ m/s. Now, change in momentum, $\Delta p$, is equal to impulse, or force times $\Delta t$.

The amount of force, or basically disturbing its inertial state of rest, is equal to the change in momentum over change in time. Going back to the example, for the same amount of time, it would take the same amount of force to bring them both to rest.

Thinking of it this way, your interpretation is correct. However don't depend on it, rather, understand the relationship between momentum, and force and intertia.

Answer (score 0):

It would, perhaps, be better to say that **mass** is a factor describing how momentum is *converted* into motion in the sense that mass factors into the conversion of momentum into velocity, which more directly specifies the motion, but momentum is the more fundamental physical quantity. Mass determines how fast an object with a given momentum moves. However, the relationship is, because mass is based intuitively on the "amount of stuff", somewhat counterintuitive when viewed this way: *lower* mass is more effective at converting momentum into motion than higher mass, i.e. it moves faster at any given momentum. Namely, we have the relation

$$\mathbf{v} = \left(\frac{1}{m}\right) \mathbf{p}$$

between the velocity $\mathbf{v}$ of a moving object and its momentum $\mathbf{p}$. Hence, perhaps, an alternative way to phrase this, in turn, may be that mass "resists" the conversion of momentum to motion.

Alternatively, we may consider

$$ч := \frac{1}{m}$$

as a novel physical quantity which we may call the "susceptibility of motion". Now, the higher this quantity, the more readily momentum manifests as motion, i.e. the faster an object with the given momentum moves. Having multiple pictures of something is often more useful than being wedded to one single picture, as long as one knows how to interrelate them.